# Checking between two textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I am working on a change password windows form application in C# (visual studio). This is how my application will work, after the user have enter their *new password* and pass the textbox validation a tick will be shown beside the *new password* textbox.

The problem i am facing is how can i check that the retyped password is same as the new password that is being entered? After checking that they are the same, the tick will appear to show the user that it is checked and the same. I do not want to click any button to check both the textbox instead checking once the user have stop typing. How can i do that?

Comment: Why don't you check it on TextChanging event of the textbox, but this will check when the control will loose the focus, not while the user is typing. How would you determine if the user has stopped typing ?

Comment: Text Changing Event? Sorry but i am abit new to this, is that any examples i can see from? Of how it works?

Comment: I would use one of the key events like KeyDown of KeyPress or KeyUp. You can execute your comparision directly when a character changes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new windows forms project. Put two textboxes on the form, nothing more. Use their default names of `textBox1` and `textBox2` Put the code below in `Form1.cs` (as this is the default name of the file). Now when ever a user has pressed a key, the comparement will be made. If the text is the same, the backcolor of the textboxes becomes green, otherwise it becomes red.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            textBox1.KeyUp += textBox_Compare;
            textBox2.KeyUp += textBox_Compare;
        }

        private void textBox_Compare(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            Color cBackColor = Color.Red;
            if (textBox1.Text == textBox2.Text)
            {
                cBackColor = Color.Green;
            }
            textBox1.BackColor = cBackColor;
            textBox2.BackColor = cBackColor;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I did not use the designer to attach the KeyUp event, I did that in the constructor of Form1: `textBox1.KeyUp += textBox_Compare;`

Comment: In the given example above, it would actually be more efficient to check if the text in both textboxes are unequal, as the comparement does not have to compare all characters, but stops whenever a character is mismatched. Although this is a very minor performance increase, its about the way of thinking ;)

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use `TextChanged` listener function. Or `keyDown` event.

Sample Code:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox2;

this.textBox1.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(passwordChanged);
this.textBox2.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(passwordChanged);

private void passwordChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String newPassword1 = textBox1.Text;
    String newPassword2 = textBox2.Text;
    if (!newPassword1.Equals(newPassword2))
    {
        textBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;
        textBox2.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
    else
    {
        textBox1.BackColor = Color.White;
        textBox2.BackColor = Color.White;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to show me how it works? I am researching online but i cant seems to understand..

Comment: Sorry, it was too late last night.. so I just went to sleep.. I've modified my answer and provide a sample code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should validate the text in the `LostFocus` of the re-enter password `TextBox`. Here you can check if the text in both the fields match or not and show the appropriate message. Also this would be triggered only once when the user has completed the part.

Comment: Is there an example of how LostFocus can be used for my code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Add an textchanged event on both textbox
To do this, go to properties of textbox, click the "Thunderstorm" icon, roll to the "Text changed" double click, then once the textbox's text changed, the event will be triggered.

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             //label1 = your tick
            label1.Visible = false;
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //if same, show, if different, hide
            if (string.Compare(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, true) == 0)
                label1.Visible = true;
            else
                label1.Visible = false;
        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             //if same, show, if different, hide
            if (string.Compare(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, true) == 0)
                label1.Visible = true;
            else
                label1.Visible = false;
        }
```